# How can range partitioning be created in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, partitioning, amazon-athena

Suppose there is an external table in AWS Athena containing a column 'Id' which is an integer along with numerous other columns.

Is there a way for partitioning this table on 'Id' column by range?

For example, create partition in the following manner:

```
0 >= Id < 10
10 >= Id < 20
20 >= Id < 30
30 >= Id < 40
```

and so on..

This could be useful when the amount of data for one value of Id is not large enough. We could then keep the data corresponding to a range in one bucket and reduce the partitioning overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, however, you won't be able to use it as a normal partition. Partitioning is usually used to reduce the amount of data being read for each query and therefore improving the query performance. This is why most of the time people chose partition keys like dt=2019-11-05. What is your actual goal here?  You can achieve the same with bucketing. and just create as many buckets as many ranges you want to have.